# Developing an encoder/decoder for image modification

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, autoencoder, image-preprocessing

On the project I am currently working on, my goal is to train a neural network to convert images of circles to ellipses in a way that models convolution/blurring in real imaging processes.

What remains is to construct a neural network, preferably a CNN, that has the desired results - i.e. takes an image with circles as an input and returns an image with ellipses. However, I have not been able to do this. At best, neural nets (including CNNs) that I have used so far have at best returned blurred images of the circles. I can't tell whether it is the fault of the neural network or the fault of the preprocessing code I am using.

Below, I will show you my code.

First, importing the necessary modules:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, Reshape
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import math
from math import sqrt
from keras.models import Model, load_model
```

Next, creating and storing the input (circle) and output (ellipse) images:

```
def create_blank_image(size):
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(size, size))
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(0, size):
            data[[i], [j]] = 0
    #print(data)

    return data

def circle_randomizer():
    number_of_circles = random.randint(4,10)
    intensity = np.ndarray(shape=(128, 128))
    #print(number_of_circles)
    radius_list = []


    for i in range(number_of_circles):
        radius_list.append(random.uniform(8, 10))
    #print(radius_list)

    center_coords = np.zeros((2,1))    
    center_coords[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
    center_coords[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)

    for i in range(number_of_circles):
      #temp_array = np.ndarray(shape=(2,1))
      #temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
      #temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)

      if i > 0:
          j = 0
          #print(i,j)
          while j in range(i):
              #print(i,j)
              #print(center_coords)
              temp_array = np.ndarray(shape=(2,1))
              temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
              temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
              #while sqrt((center_coords[[0],[i]] - center_coords[[0],[j]])**2 + (center_coords[[1],[i]] - center_coords[[1],[j]])**2) < radius_list[i] + radius_list[j]:
              while sqrt((temp_array[[0],[0]] - center_coords[[0],[j]])**2 + (temp_array[[1],[0]] - center_coords[[1],[j]])**2) < radius_list[i] + radius_list[j]:               
                  temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
                  temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
                  j = 0
              center_coords = np.concatenate((center_coords,temp_array), axis = 1)          
              j = j + 1
              #print('loop ran ' + str(j) + ' times')

    return radius_list, center_coords

def image_creator(centers, radii, img_data, size):
    x = np.arange(1, size, 1)
    y = np.arange(1, size, 1)

    for c in range(len(centers)):
        x0 = centers[[c],[0]]
        y0 = centers[[c],[1]]
        radius = radii[c]
        for i in range(0, size-1):
            for j in range(0, size-1):
                height2 = radius**2 - (x[i]-x0)**2 - (y[j]-y0)**2
                if height2 >= 0:
                    img_data[[i], [j]] = sqrt(radius**2 - (x[i]-x0)**2 - (y[j]-y0)**2)

    return img_data

def make_ellipses(size, radii, center_coords):
    # idea: use a random number generator to create a random rotation of the x,y axes for the ellipse

    # size is the length of a side of the square
    # length is the length of the ellipse
    # defined as equal to the radius of the circle later

    my_label = np.ndarray(shape=(size, size))
    x = np.arange(1, size, 1)
    y = np.arange(1, size, 1)

    # inefficiently zero the array
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(0, size):
            my_label[[i], [j]] = 0
            # print(my_label)
    for c in range(len(center_coords)):
        x0 = center_coords[[c],[0]]
        y0 = center_coords[[c],[1]]
        #theta = random.uniform(0, 6.28318)
        theta = 0.775

        for i in range(0, size - 1):
            for j in range(0, size - 1):
                xprime = (x[i] - x0) * math.cos(theta) + (y[j] - y0) * math.sin(theta)
                yprime = -(x[i] - x0) * math.sin(theta) + (y[j] - y0) * math.cos(theta)
                height2 = (0.5 * radii[c]) ** 2 - 0.25 * xprime ** 2 - yprime ** 2
                if height2 >= 0:
                    my_label[[i], [j]] = sqrt((0.5 * radii[c]) ** 2 - 0.25 * xprime ** 2 - yprime ** 2)

    return my_label

size = 128
radii, centers = circle_randomizer()
#print(radii)
#print(centers)

#Make labels and samples consistent with rest of code
N = 100
circle_images = []
ellipse_images = []
coords = []
for sample in range(0, N):
    blank_image = create_blank_image(size)
    radii, centers = circle_randomizer()
    temp_image = image_creator(centers, radii, blank_image, size)
    circle_images.append(temp_image)
    temp_output = make_ellipses(size, radii, centers)
    ellipse_images.append(temp_output)
    coords.append(centers)
#print(labels)
#print(samples[0][40])
```

Storing the images in files:

```
filenames = []
for i in range(0,N):
  np.save('ellipses_' + str(i) + '.npy', ellipse_images[i])
  filenames.append('ellipses_' + str(i) + '.npy')
  np.save('circles_' + str(i) + '.npy', circle_images[i])
circles_stack = np.stack(circle_images,axis=0)
ellipses_stack = np.stack(ellipse_images,axis=0)
np.save('ellipses_stack.npy', ellipses_stack)
np.save('circles_stack.npy', circles_stack)
```

Loading the images:

```
# load training images and corresponding "labels"
# training samples
training_images_path = 'circles_stack.npy'
labels_path = 'ellipses_stack.npy'

X = np.load(training_images_path,'r')/20.
y = np.load(labels_path,'r')/20.
```

Defining the image preprocessing functions: (I'm not sure why preprocessing_X and preprocessing_y are different; this is code I've partially adopted from a research paper.)

```
# Preprocessing for training images
def preprocessing_X(image_data, image_size):
    image_data = image_data.reshape(image_data.shape[0], image_size[0], image_size[1], 1)
    image_data = image_data.astype('float32')
    image_data = (image_data - np.amin(image_data))/(np.amax(image_data) - np.amin(image_data))
    return image_data


​
# preprocessing for "labels" (ground truth)
def preprocessing_Y(image_data, image_size):
    n_images = 0
    label = np.array([])
    for idx in range(image_data.shape[0]):
        img = image_data[idx,:,:]
        n, m = img.shape
        img = np.array(OneHotEncoder(n_values=nb_classes).fit_transform(img.reshape(-1,1)).todense())
        img = img.reshape(n, m, nb_classes)
        label = np.append(label, img)
        n_images += 1
    label_4D = label.reshape(n_images, image_size[0], image_size[1], nb_classes)    
    return label_4D
```

Preprocessing the images:

```
# Split into train/test and make the shapes of tensors compatible with tensorflow format
nb_classes = 10
target_size = (128, 128)

#Below line randomizes which images are picked for train/test sets. ~20% will go to test.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
X_train = preprocessing_X(X_train, target_size)
X_test = preprocessing_X(X_test, target_size)
y_train = preprocessing_Y(y_train, target_size)
y_test = preprocessing_Y(y_test, target_size)
```

Somebody suggested an encoder-decoder pair, but I do not know how to implement this. Any suggestions?

EDIT: A commenter asked me to show the Keras model I've been using, so here it is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(nb_classes, kernel_size=3, padding = 'same',
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(128,128,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(nb_classes, (1, 1), activation = 'linear', padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Compiling the model:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

model.save("/content/artificial_label_train.h5")
model.save_weights("/content/artificial_label_train_weights.h5")
```

Comment: Try including the code for the Keras model too.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have made the requested edit. If you could please comment on how I could improve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should try including some more convolution layers both in the encoder and decoder models.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I'm not sure if what I've been using qualifies as an encoder/decoder model. When I do add more convolutional layers, the results get worse.